# Foreign-key-like merge in R

Tags: r

I'm merging a bunch of `csv` with 1 row per id/pk/seqn.

```
> full = merge(demo, lab13am, by="seqn", all=TRUE)
> full = merge(full, cdq, by="seqn", all=TRUE)
> full = merge(full, mcq, by="seqn", all=TRUE)
> full = merge(full, cfq, by="seqn", all=TRUE)
> full = merge(full, diq, by="seqn", all=TRUE)
> print(length(full$ridageyr))
[1] 9965
> print(summary(full$ridageyr))
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
   0.00   11.00   19.00   29.73   48.00   85.00
```

Everything is great. But, I have another file which has multiple rows per id like:

```
"seqn","rxd030","rxd240b","nhcode","rxq250"
56,2,"","",NA,NA,""
57,1,"ACETAMINOPHEN","01200",2
57,1,"BUDESONIDE","08800",1
58,1,"99999","",NA
```

`57` has two rows. So, if I naively try to merge this file, I have a ton more rows and my data gets all skewed up.

```
> full = merge(full, rxq, by="seqn", all=TRUE)
> print(length(full$ridageyr))
[1] 15643
> print(summary(full$ridageyr))
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
   0.00   14.00   41.00   40.28   66.00   85.00
```

Is there a normal idiomatic way to deal with data like this? For instance, say i would like to create a column on `full` that has whether or not the participants have taken an RX in the last 30 days. I can get lists of keys with something like:

```
has_taken <- unique(rxq[rxq$rxd030 == "1",]$seqn)
hasnt_tak <- unique(rxq[rxq$rxd030 == "2",]$seqn)
full$takenRX <- ifelse(full$seqn %in% has_taken, TRUE, ifelse(full$seqn %in% hasnt_tak, FALSE, NA))
```

Now I have a `takenRX` column which I think correctly gives me TRUE/FALSE/NA for each row in my `full` data frame. Do I need to do something like this manually for each bit of data or is there a more automated way that I can bring this data with multiple rows per key into my data frame? Is there a more elegant suggestion? A more idiomatic approach?

For other columns, I think I would like to combine the rows so that there are ~tuples.

```
key, a, b, c
2, 0, 0, 0
```

PLUS

```
key, baz
2, foo
2, bar
```

gives me something like:

```
key, a, b, c, baz
2, 0, 0, 0, [foo, bar]
```

However, I'm not sure what data structure to use for the `[foo, bar]` so I can easily use "has foo in baz" as a logical later.

To play along at home, there is/was some code [here](https://github.com/skyl/NHANES-opensource/blob/ea77815dbc5c14082a76b9fe075a540d0411015e/1999-2000/ldl.R#L60)

Comment: I guess that strategy might work for single drug ids but a single drug id may indicate multiple different medication components, so I think you really should be using the FDACODE categories. "Aldatactazide "for instance has aldactone and hydrochlorthizide in it.

Answer (score 3):

To your updated example:

```
demog <- data.frame(key=c(2, 3), a=c(1,0), b=letters[1:2], c=LETTERS[1:2])
meds <- data.frame(key=c(2,2), baz=c('foo', 'baz'), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
aggregate(baz~key, data=meds, FUN=list)
#  key      baz
#1   2 foo, baz

merge(demog, mermed)
#  key a b c      baz
#1   2 1 a A foo, baz
```

You will need to add all.x=TRUE to a real case if you don't want to loose the case with no meds, Part of my criticism of your question was the lack of a sufficiently large test case to expose other such coding deficiencies.

```
> merge(demog, mermed, all.x=T)
  key a b c      baz
1   2 1 a A foo, baz
2   3 0 b B       NA
```

(I still think the following applies.)
You may need to construct a sensible categorization of medications of interest and for each person level record create a single record noting whether they are taking one from the categories of interest for your research. I was wondering if those "rxd030" or "rxq250" codes might be a clinical grouping that compresses the lipid-lowering agents? (Turns out that is not the case.) This points to the need for questioners to supply meaning as well as code in order to get sensible advice.

A bit of searching suggests this may already have been done. This is a small snipped from the NHANES 1999-2000 webpage for medications:

```
Codebook

    SEQN - Respondent sequence number
    RXD030 - Taken prescription medicine/past month
    RXD240B - Standard generic ingredient name
    NHCODE - Standard generic ingredient code
    RXQ250 - Medicine container seen by interviewer
    RXD260 - Number of days taken medicine
    FDACODE1 - FDA/NDC drug class code 1 
    FDACODE2 - FDA/NDC drug class code 2
    FDACODE3 - FDA/NDC drug class code 3
    FDACODE4 - FDA/NDC drug class code 4
    FDACODE5 - FDA/NDC drug class code 5
    FDACODE6 - FDA/NDC drug class code 6
```

There's also an appendix that has some counts:

```
Code or Value   Value Description   Count   Cumulative  Skip to Item
Generic drug code   Value was recorded  9138     9138   
        < blank >   Missing             6505    15643
```

And one of the med codes is: 912    HYPERLIPIDEMIA

So it looks like you do not need to reinvent the wheel, but rather can use the categorization that has already been done.

You first need to create a variable based on "RXD030: Have you taken or used any prescription medicines in the past month?" The "no" cases will all be 0 for every category.

I imported the data into R and looked at the "hyperlipemia drugs". It turns out that only FDACODE1 and FDACODE2 are used for the "0912" categories. Here are the first ten SEQN's for the two codes that match. I offer this to help you construct a proper question:

```
> subset( medrecs,  FDACODE2 %in% "0912" )[1:10,"SEQN"]
 [1]   46   86   90  191  434 1029 1273 1634 1980 2105
> subset( medrecs,  FDACODE1 %in% "0912" )[1:10,"SEQN"]
 [1]  29  55  86 130 148 179 187 211 239 274
```

A proper question would offer access to ALL the med records from some or all of these, as well as some sample med records that did not have them AND would have the "demog" records to match to.

Comment: I'm not trying to categorize but rather bring together multiple rows in the RX data into the `full` data. Edited to try to clarify.

Comment: I tried to give you guidance about how to do what you requested but your proposal to select individual drugs on the basis of single values of rxq$rxddrgid looks doomed to frustration. You need to decide what FDACODE categories you want examine and then create single Y/N variables that are indicators of whether any of the 6 FDACODE columns for any of a person's RX records have that category number in them. You have not constructed a proper question to allow people to answer that question. Build an example people can work with.

Comment: I'm looking for idiomatic syntax for merging the RX data, with multiple rows per key, into the other data which has 1 row per key, not looking for guidance about how to analyze the data.

Comment: I again tried to clarify the question. Though, I have no idea what you mean by `A proper question would offer access to ALL the med records from some or all of these, as well as some sample med records that did not have them AND would have the "demog" records to match to.` The complete dataset is available. Do you mean "a proper inquiry into the data" or am I right to interpret this statement as a critique of my SO question?

Comment: I'm using your general suggestion to factor on the fdacodes. Thanks for the input. I don't know if I should just change the question to fit with the answer at this point :D

Comment: What I meant by a "proper question" was one that offered  code needed to access the data: i.e. a read.table(...) call that got it into the workspace. If you are just saying ... "it's out there , somewhere, you go get it" ... makes it much less likely to awaken people's interest. I was already interested in the topic, but I'm a bit weird, so I'm not surprised that you had modest interest expressed.

Comment: OH! I didn't even realize that I had not provided a link to what I had done: https://github.com/skyl/NHANES-opensource/blob/master/1999-2000/ldl.R#L60 ! I will add to the question. I have some approaches to this brewing.

Comment: I would be happy to correspond privately. My email address should be easy to pull from r-help.